# A third order nonlinear ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve $$y'''(t)+a(y''(t))^2+b(y'(t))^3=0$$

Could one make some kind of least common denominator argument to decide possible substitutions? Since the chain rule will come into play, I suppose a substitution both for the variable $t$ and the function $y$ could be useful. Possibly some powers of them?

Comment: You could reduce the order simply by doing $x(t)=y'(t)$.

Comment: Also note that $y(t)=\text{const}$ is a (somewhat trivial) solution.

Comment: This came from the one we solved before, @Dylan I just added a term to make it a bit tougher.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Adrian suggests, let $y'=z$, to get the second order equation
$$
z''+a\,(z')^2+b\,z^3=0.
$$
Since the independent variable $t$ does not appear explicitly in the equation (I am assuming $a$ and $b$ are constants), we let
$$
z'=p,\quad z''=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{dp}{dz}\,\frac{dz}{dt}=p\,\frac{dp}{dz}.
$$
This gives the first order equation
$$
p\,\frac{dp}{dz}+a\,p^2+b\,z^3=0,
$$
which written as
$$
\frac{dp}{dz}=-a\,p-b\,z^3\,p^{-1}
$$
is a Bernoulli equation. To solve it, let $u=p^2$. This gives the linear equation
$$
\frac{du}{dz}=-a\,u-b\,z^3.
$$
I have not done the calculations, but my impression is that you will not be able to get an explicit solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like this, but you were so much faster! +1

Comment: Sorry, what just happened...?! So confused... you added new variable and that somehow made it easier? How is $\frac{dp(t)}{dz(t)}=-a\,p(t)-b\,z(t)^3\,p(t)^{-1}$ any better than the original? (I'm not familiar with the solution of Bernoulli's equation.)

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain how to solve the equation.

Comment: The solution to the last equation is $u=C\exp(-az)+6b/a^4-bz^3/a+3bz^2/a^2-6bz/a^3$ according to MATLAB. This kind of "linear" equations can be solved by combining general solution $u=C\exp(-az)$ of the homogeneous part $\frac{du}{dz}=-a\,u$, and one particular solution of the original equation, a polynomial with similar degree to $-bz^3$.

Comment: @jingyu9575 My comment was about the difficulty of getting an explicit solution the equation $z'=p(z)$.

Answer (score 7):

$$y'''(t)+a(y''(t))^2+b(y'(t))^3=0$$
Substitute $z=y'$
$$z''(t)+a(z'(t))^2+bz^3=0$$
Substitute $p=z'$
$$\frac {dp}{dz}p+ap^2+bz^3=0$$
$$\frac 12(p^2)'+ap^2+bz^3=0$$
Finally substitute $w=p^2$
$$\frac 12w'+aw+bz^3=0$$
Bernouilli's equation

Answer (score 3):

As a more general solution, if you have an equation of the form 
$$ x''(t) + a(x(t))x'(t)^2+b(x(t)) = 0 $$
then you can make the substitution $f(x) = x'(t)^2$ to arrive at the equation
$$ \frac{1}{2}f'(x) + a(x)f(x)+b(x)= 0 $$
Letting $\mu(x) = \exp\left[\int a(x) dx\right]$, we can solve for $f(x)$:
$$ f(x) = \mu(x)^{-1}\left(C_1-2\int\mu(x)b(x)dx\right) $$
which can be substituted back for $x(t)$:
$$ x' = \mu(x)^{-1/2}\left(C_1-2\int\mu(x)b(x)dx\right)^{1/2} $$
and solved implicitly:
$$ C_2 + t - \int \left[ \mu(x)\left(C_1-2\int\mu(x)b(x)dx\right)^{-1} \right]^{1/2} dx = 0 $$

Comment: but $f'(x) = (x'(t)^2)' =/\text{ chain rule }/= 2x'(t)x''(t) \neq x''(t)$

Comment: $df/dx = \frac{df/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{2x'x''}{x'} = 2x''$. I'm missing a factor of 1/2 there, but otherwise it's correct. I've fixed that error now. See here for substitution: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0344.pdf

Comment: I see you switched variables now. Prim notation is confusing when you do that